# Python 2.7 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, ironpython

I am new to Python and working with a set of objects (Node) and just trying to iterate over the set of objects and printout the variable 'H'. Unfortunately I keep getting the error: ("AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'H'"). Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my class Node that is stored in the set.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, row, col, heuristic):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.H = heuristic
        self.parent = None

    @classmethod
    def with_parent(self, row, col, heuristic, parent):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.H = heuristic
        self.parent = parent
```

Here is the set with the first Node being entered. Later on more nodes are entered but for now just adding one is still creating a headache

```
open_list = set()
start_row, start_col = start_loc
open_list.add(Node(start_row, start_col, 0))
```

And here is the line of code throwing the error: ("AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'H'")

```
for open_node in open_list:
    sys.stdout.write("H: " + str(open_node.H))
```

Once I can get this worked out the real goal is to sort on the Heuristic.

```
current = sorted(open_list, key=lambda open: open.H)[0]
```

Comment: You get this exception at the expression `open_node.H` because at some point in your program `open_node` has the value `None` at that point in the code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you showed. Try create a small test.py which will reproduce the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'H'" means that one of the Nodes in `open_list` is being assigned the value 'None' instead of being initialized. Does anything happen to `open_list` between the lines you show and the line with an error?

Comment: This looks to be it. In the "between the lines" I was calling with_parent method on the node without initializing it first. I'm guessing this is why I was getting a NoneType object. It stems from my misuse of a @classmathod as an init override. The easy fix was to add parent as part of the constructor and just pass in None as parent value for the first Node. Thanks a ton!